# MultipartFile Upload : 415 Unsupported MediaType

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, multipartform-data, multipartfile

I want to upload the file with spring boot and vue.
But, I have an error '415 : Unsupported MediaType'.

This is my spring boot controller.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value = "회원 가입", notes = "<strong>아이디와 패스워드</strong>를 통해 회원가입 한다.") 
@ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "성공"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "인증 실패"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "사용자 없음"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "서버 오류")
})
public ResponseEntity<User> register(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    ...

}
```

And, this is my vue code.

```
<el-form-item prop="profileImg" label="프로필 사진" :label-width="state.formLabelWidth" >
  <input @change="fileSelect()" id="profileimg" type="file" accept="image/*">
</el-form-item>

const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('userId', state.form.userId)
        formData.append('userName', state.form.userName)
        formData.append('password', state.form.password)
        formData.append('age', state.form.age)
        formData.append('gender', state.form.gender)
        formData.append('phoneNum', state.form.phoneNum)
        formData.append('email', state.form.email)
        formData.append('mbti', state.form.mbti)
        formData.append('guide', state.form.guide)
        formData.append('file', state.form.profileImg)

profileImg ({ commit }, payload) {
  return axios
    .post(`${BASE_URL}/api/v1/users`, payload,
      { 
        headers: {
          "Accept": "*/*", 
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      }
    )
}
```

I tried `@RequestPart MultipartFile file`, but had the same error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you drop your `consumes` parameter and let Spring auto-negotiate it?

Comment: I got same error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't add comments, this answer is just my guess

what if you output

```
request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
```

Content-Type may have been changed if your request pass through Nginx or other agent

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13268)
All you have to do is change

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

with :

```
@RequestParam("file") FilePart file)
```